# exception in thread main: method is undefined for the type

Tags: java

I am working on creating a dice game simulation and got the following error:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method displayGrandWinner(Player, Player) is undefined for the type ChoHan
```

I am going to post all of the code for this class below because I am not sure where the error is, but I think the only necessary code is the `displayGrandWinner` method:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ChoHan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MAX_ROUNDS = 5; // Number of rounds 
        String player1Name;  // First player's name
        String player2Name; //Second player's name

         // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        //Get the player's names
        System.out.println("Enter the firs tplayers name:");
        player1Name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second players name:");
        player2Name = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Create the dealer
        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

        //Create the two players
        Player player1 = new Player(player1Name);
        Player player2 = new Player(player2Name);

        //play the rounds
        for(int round = 0; round < MAX_ROUNDS; round++){

            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.printf("Now playing round %d.\n", round+1);

            //roll the dice 
            dealer.rollDice();

            //the players make their guesses
            player1.makeGuess();
            player2.makeGuess();

            //determine the winner of this round
            roundResults(dealer, player1, player2);
        }

        //Display the grand winner 
        displayGrandWinner(player1, player2);
    }

    /**
     * The roundResults method determines the results of the current round
     * @param dealer The Dealer object
     * @param player1 Player #1 object
     * @param player2 Player #2 object
     */

    public static void roundResults(Dealer dealer, Player player1, Player player2){
        //Show the dice values
        System.out.printf("The dealer rolled %d and %d.\n", dealer.getDie1Value(), dealer.getDie2Value());
        System.out.printf("Result: %s\n", dealer.getChoOrHan());

        //Check each players guess and award points 
        checkGuess(player1, dealer);
        checkGuess(player2, dealer);
    }

    /**
     * The checkGuess method checks a player's guess against the dealer's result.
     * @param player The Player object to check 
     * @param dealer The Dealer object
     */

    public static void checkGuess(Player player, Dealer dealer){
        final int POINTS_TO_ADD = 1; //points to award the winner
        String guess = player.getGuess(); //player's guess
        String choHanResult = dealer.getChoOrHan(); //Cho or Han

        //display the player's guess
        System.out.printf("The player %s guessed %s\n", player.getName(), player.getGuess());

        //award points if the player guessed correctly
        if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase(choHanResult)){
            player.addPoints(POINTS_TO_ADD);
            System.out.printf("Awarding %d points to %s\n", POINTS_TO_ADD,player.getName());
        }

        /**
         * The displayGrandWinner method displays the games grand winner
         * @param player1 Player #1
         * @param player2 Player #2
         */

    public static void displayGrandWinner(Player player1, Player player2){
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Game over. Here are the results:");
        System.out.printf("%s: %d points.\n", player1.getName(), player1.getPoints());
        System.out.printf("%s: %d points.\n", player2.getName(), player2.getPoints());

        if(player1.getPoints() > player2.getPoints())
            System.out.println(player1.getName() +" is the winner");
        else if(player2.getPoints() > player1.getPoints()) 
            System.out.println(player2.getName() +" is the winner");
        else
            System.out.println("Tie");

        }
    }


}
```

Why is the `displayGrandWinner` method not registering as part of the `ChoHan` class?

Comment: Make sure you compile your code properly. You are getting a runtime error on a compilation error so your class file might not be re-built. Did you save your source file before building?

Comment: it is. maybe you forgot to re-compile your code after altering it?

Comment: This code does not compile. Your curly braces are not placed correctly. For example, the checkGuess() method does not close where you would expect it to. Fix your curly braces, recompile, and try again.

Comment: isn't displayGrandWinner inside checkGuess method?

Comment: @Derek thank you, this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else also